# A $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ -fiber bundle which do not admit a n-dimensional vector bundle structure

Tags: vector-bundles, fibre-bundles

Is there  a  fiber  bundle $(E,B, \mathbb{R}^{n})$, with typical  fiber $\mathbb{R}^{n}$,  such that there  is  no any  $n$-dimensional vector  bundle  structure on the  pair  $(E,B)$? That is  there is  no  a continuous  map  $p:E \to B$  such that the triple $(E,B,P)$ would  be  a $n$ dimensional vector  bundle.

Comment: You might want to look for the universal case $BTop(n)$ in the literature.

Comment: see  "Open and Closed Disk Bundles" by William Browder, https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970428.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such a fibre bundle does not exists if you suppose that it is endowed with a differentiable structure. Stewart has shown that the group of diffeomorphisms of $R^n$ retract to $O(n)$. So every $Diff(R^n)$-bundle has an $O(n)$-reduction.

Stewart, T. E. (1960). On groups of diffeomorphisms. Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, 11(4), 559-563.

Comment: Thank you very  much for your interesting answer and helpful reference.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there a lots of them.

The topological tangent bundle $\tau$ of any topological non-smoothable manifold $M$ gives you an example since a vector bundle reduction of $\tau$ is by smoothing theory equivalent to a smoothing of $M$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting answer. Unfortunately I can not accept two answers  simultaneously.